# Unable to add new rules in SonarQube and raise the issues on the created rules

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a requirement of adding new rules into the SonarQube and implement it in my source code and raise issues for the same. I am following the procedure in the below link:
docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Custom+Rules+for+Java

I have also downloaded the sample plugin from the below link and gone through the steps;
github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples

But from the plugin i downloaded, I see the rules coded in path\plugins\java-custom-rules\src\main\java\org\sonar\samples\java are not shown in the Rules tab.

Also, the issues for these particular rules are not shown in the dashboard for the project.

As seen in the above snapshot, all these issues are existing ones and not the ones we coded.

Is there any other way to add rules or am I following the correct procedure. There is no clear documentation about this anywhere.
If there is any other method other than this can anyone please let me know. Or if any changes to be made in the above step please let me know.

Also, I am able to create rules in UI. But not able to add to JAVA coding guidelines.
 I have followed the below link for this,
docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Rules
Is there any procedure to link these rules with the code?

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks,
Shruthi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you created the exact same thread in our SonarQube google group. I won't respond on this topic. Please follow the discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/sonarqube/asP4Z2uhXuw/omIp5-k0AAAJ